My AdMob recently sent me this warning of my app: Layout Encourages Accidental Clicks - Unexpected Launch Interstitials. (Jetpack Compose)
My app is written in Kotlin using Jetpack Compose. And I believe this warning cause by the ad is being load after the user navigate back to a screen.
This is how my MainActivity.kt looks like
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd? = null
    private var adId: String = "some_id_123456"
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val currentTheme = isSystemInDarkTheme()
            var darkTheme by remember { mutableStateOf(currentTheme) }
            var adStatus by remember{ mutableStateOf(false) }

            MyAppTheme(
                darkTheme = darkTheme
            ) {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    MY_APP(
                        darkTheme = darkTheme,
                        onThemeUpdated = { darkTheme = !darkTheme },
                        onBackButtonClicked = {
                            if(adStatus){
                                showInterstitialAd()
                                adStatus = false
                            } else {
                                loadInterstitialAd {
                                    adStatus = it
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //ad
    private fun loadInterstitialAd(adStatus:(Boolean) -> Unit){
        val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
        InterstitialAd.load(
            this,
            adId,
            adRequest,
            object : InterstitialAdLoadCallback(){
                override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
                    super.onAdFailedToLoad(adError)
                    mInterstitialAd = null
                    adStatus.invoke(false)
                }

                override fun onAdLoaded(interstitialAd: InterstitialAd) {
                    super.onAdLoaded(interstitialAd)
                    mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd
                    adStatus.invoke(true)
                }
            }
        )
    }
    private fun showInterstitialAd(){
        mInterstitialAd?.let { ad ->
            ad.fullScreenContentCallback = object : FullScreenContentCallback(){
                override fun onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                    super.onAdShowedFullScreenContent()
                    mInterstitialAd = null
                }

            }

            ad.show(this)
        } ?: kotlin.run {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No ad shows", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}


And the MY_APP contains different routes to different screens, I only show the Interstitials Ad when move back. This is basically how I implement the move back activity.
val onMoveBack: () -> Unit = {
    onBackButtonClicked()
    navController.popBackStack()
}

I don't know how to fix this since that ad sometime just load slower than the screen.

You must have preload the interstitial ad and then when you navigate between screen show it before actual screen switching code.

I actually lift the issue without actually change anything in the code. I just said the issues was a mistake and AdMob agreed

I have never encountered this issue in my Jetpack compose app

Thanks for your help. And about the pre-loading the ads, how do you actually achieve that

First when app loads with that i also load the interstitial ad and when ad show complete or dismissed i again load it. and when required show it.
